# QGIS: reopen project with empty attribute table

Tags: attribute-table

I have creat a Grid layer by Vector grid on QGIS 2.18. Then I saved this project and reopen it, the Grid layer just cannot be shown and its attribute table becomes empty.

May I know what is going wrong here?

[image]

Comment: îs your grid layer a temporary layer?

Comment: @LaughU. I am new to QGIS, what is a temporary layer, and how to convert it to permanent layer?

Answer (score 1):

The `Vector grid` output is a temporary layer, unless you specified a filename and folder on your disk in the tool's dialogue form.

You can use `Save As` **BEFORE** exiting QGIS to turn a temporary to a permanent layer, again specifying filename and folder.